# Google Maps "Places API"

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I'm working on a store locator using Google Maps Platform. But the option that allow me to get users input, the Places API is only showing places from the UK and I want to find locations in Mexico.

[image: I tried to search Zapopan and these are the options that the API shows.]

I really want to know if there is some way to change that. I'm going to add my project code.

Thanks for reading.

```js
function initMap() {
  // Create the map.
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 6,
    center: { lat: 23.81069, lng: -102.25753 },
  });

  // Load the stores GeoJSON onto the map.
  map.data.loadGeoJson('stores.json', {idPropertyName: 'storeid'});
  
  const apiKey = 'APIKEY'
  const infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  // Show the information for a store when its marker is clicked.
  map.data.addListener('click', (event) => {
    const category = event.feature.getProperty('category');
    const name = event.feature.getProperty('name');
    const description = event.feature.getProperty('description');
    const hours = event.feature.getProperty('hours');
    const phone = event.feature.getProperty('phone');
    const position = event.feature.getGeometry().get();
    const content = `
      <h2>${name}</h2><p>${description}</p>
      <p><b>Open:</b> ${hours}<br/><b>Phone:</b> ${phone}</p>
    `;

    infoWindow.setContent(content);
    infoWindow.setPosition(position);
    infoWindow.setOptions({pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -30)});
    infoWindow.open(map);
  });
  // Build and add the search bar
  const card = document.createElement('div');
  const titleBar = document.createElement('div');
  const title = document.createElement('div');
  const container = document.createElement('div');
  const input = document.createElement('input');
  const options = {
    types: ['address'],
    componentRestrictions: {country: 'gb'},
  };

  card.setAttribute('id', 'pac-card');
  title.setAttribute('id', 'title');
  title.textContent = 'Find the nearest store';
  titleBar.appendChild(title);
  container.setAttribute('id', 'pac-container');
  input.setAttribute('id', 'pac-input');
  input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  input.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Enter an address');
  container.appendChild(input);
  card.appendChild(titleBar);
  card.appendChild(container);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(card);

  // Make the search bar into a Places Autocomplete search bar and select
  // which detail fields should be returned about the place that
  // the user selects from the suggestions.
  const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

  autocomplete.setFields(
      ['address_components', 'geometry', 'name']);
      // Set the origin point when the user selects an address
  const originMarker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map});
  originMarker.setVisible(false);
  let originLocation = map.getCenter();

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', async () => {
    originMarker.setVisible(false);
    originLocation = map.getCenter();
    const place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    if (!place.geometry) {
      // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
      // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
      window.alert('No address available for input: \'' + place.name + '\'');
      return;
    }

    // Recenter the map to the selected address
    originLocation = place.geometry.location;
    map.setCenter(originLocation);
    map.setZoom(9);
    console.log(place);

    originMarker.setPosition(originLocation);
    originMarker.setVisible(true);

    // Use the selected address as the origin to calculate distances
    // to each of the store locations
    const rankedStores = await calculateDistances(map.data, originLocation);
    showStoresList(map.data, rankedStores);

    return;
  });


}
```

```css
#map {
    height: 100%;
  }

  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  /* Styling for Autocomplete search bar */
  #pac-card {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Roboto;
    margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: none;
  }

  #pac-container {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    margin-right: 12px;
  }

  #pac-input {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-left: 12px;
    padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 400px;
  }

  #pac-input:focus {
    border-color: #4d90fe;
  }

  #title {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #acbcc9;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 6px 12px;
  }

  .hidden {
    display: none;
  }

  /* Styling for an info pane that slides out from the left.
   * Hidden by default. */
  #panel {
    height: 100%;
    width: null;
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
  }

  .open {
    width: 250px;
  }

  .place {
    font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-block-end: 0px;
    padding-left: 18px;
    padding-right: 18px;
  }

  .distanceText {
    color: silver;
    font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-block-start: 0.25em;
    padding-left: 18px;
    padding-right: 18px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map By Glamerstone</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- The div to hold the map -->
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I removed the API key from your code, please don't share API keys on public websites for security purposes.

Answer (score 1):

```
  const options = {
    types: ['address'],
    componentRestrictions: {country: 'gb'},
  };
```

Country restriction